# array_filter leaves one 0 and one null

Tags: php, mysql

I am using array_filter to filter out 0's and nulls' from an array.

Code:

```
while ($row1 = $sth1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $rows_shared_id[$row1['shared_id']]['shared_id'] = $row1['shared_id'];

}

$erows_shared_id = array_filter($rows_shared_id);

foreach($erows_shared_id as $evalue){

    echo $evalue['shared_id'] . "<br>";

}
```

The results, without array_filter, have multiple cells with a value of 0, or null. With array_filter, it filters out all 0's and nulls, except for the first of each. So, I am left with an array with one 0 and one null value. Why is it deleting all, but the first and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using the `array_filter` function after the fact, filter out 0s and nulls while you're in the while loop for better performance.
As for why the `array_filter` function isn't working for you, I'm not sure!  I'd be interested to see your input array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_filter` works on a single level array, but yours is a two-level array.

Try mapping `array_filter` to sub-arrays of your array:

```
$erows_shared_id = array_map('array_filter', $rows_shared_id);
```

You could then filter the array again to remove any keys that have empty arrays as children.

```
$erows_shared_id = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $rows_shared_id));
```